# java bufferedreader read line after another line, not under it

Tags: java, console, line, bufferedreader

When I'm using a bufferedreader, It will skip a line then read the input the user enters. Is there a way to have it read something that comes after a line in the console from something such as a System.out.print();?

**Example:** "Enter your age here: " (read here)

**instead of:** "Enter your age here: "

(reads here)

I don't necessarily need to use a bufferedreader for all that matters, I just want it to read something after the line, not under it.

EDIT: code from a program I had laying around, which is a good example.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int y;
        int z;
        int x = 0;
        String line2 = "empty";
        String line = "empty";

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("enter 2 numbers of which the first is larger than the second");
    try {
        line = br.readLine();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        line2 = br2.readLine();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    y = Integer.parseInt(line);
    z = Integer.parseInt(line2);

    if (y < 9 && y > 5 && z > 5 && z < 9) {
        if (y > z) {
            x = (int) ((Math.random() * (y - z)) + z);
        }
        if (z > y) {
            x = (int) ((Math.random() * (z - y)) + y);
        }
    }else System.out.println("only numbers between 5 and 9!");
    int[] getallen = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        getallen[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * (y - z)) + z);
        System.out.println(getallen[i]);
    }

}
```

}

output:

```
"enter 2 numbers of which the first is larger than the second
2
5
only numbers between 5 and 9!"
```

what I want:

```
"enter 2 numbers of which the first is larger than the second 2 5
 only numbers between 5 and 9!"
```

variable names are in Dutch, but they aren't really relevant to my question anyway.

Comment: It works the way you want on my system (Windows 7, JDK 1.8.0 25)

Comment: We can be more helpful if you can post the exact code you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple programm and it worked with Eclipse by just changing the `System.out.println(...)` to `System.out.print(...)`. But you will have the problem to separate the numbers e.g. `Enter number(s): 1 2 3` will return `1 2 3` as one string.

Therefore I would suggest you to use a `Scanner` for reading the inputs because it has a `nextInt()` method, which you can pull constantly for numbers (e.g. `Enter number(s): 1 2 3` will give you at first call `1`, at second call `2` and at third call `3`)

Example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter number(s): ");
    while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        number = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number was " + number);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind: Entering anything other than an `int` will give you an exception.